# Can you create Excel addins with FCell?

Tags: excel, f#, add-in

So that you can load the user defined functions on machines that don't have installed FCell. It is my understanding that you can't load .dll into excel; only addins.

You can still open excel workbooks done with FCell on machines that don't have FCell installed (but it requires an internet connection )

Comment: Not familiar with FCELL but you can do this with Excel DNA and F# see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fsharpteam/2013/07/16/combining-f-and-excel-using-excel-dna/

Comment: @CharlesWilliams
When was the last time you used Excel DNA? I can't make it work with F#... and it is asking me to install .Net Framework 3.5!

Comment: If you have a problem with making F# and Excel DNA work I suggest you post details of the problem here or (probably better) in the Excel DNA support group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/exceldna

Comment: @LayGonzález I develop Excel-DNA and am happy to help. The forum that Charles points to is the right one for any questions. F# still works fine for add-ins when making an F# project in Visual Studio, though the F# embedded in the .dna files might not be easy to make work with current versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can embed .NET UDFs in a self contained Excel workbook with FCell. FCell is now replaced by NeXL Nuget package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/NeXL/

There are open source NeXL demo projects here:
https://github.com/Statfactory

Adam